# Error while creating new models from existing `redshift` table in loopback composer

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

Got the following error while discovering models from existing `redshift` table.

```
Oops! Something is wrong
Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
Show/hide details
Message: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
Request: /workspace/api/DataSourceDefinitions/server.bl-pgsql/discoverModelDefinition
Staus: 500
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
    at mysqlDataTypeToJSONType (/home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-connector-postgresql/lib/discovery.js:349:25)
    at /home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-connector-postgresql/lib/discovery.js:180:20
    at Array.map (native)
    at callback (/home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-connector-postgresql/lib/discovery.js:179:17)
    at /home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:166:22
    at doNotify (/home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:93:49)
    at PostgreSQL.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers (/home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:116:5)
    at PostgreSQL.ObserverMixin.notifyObserversOf (/home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:91:8)
    at cbForWork (/home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/observer.js:156:14)
    at /home/user/appname/node_modules/loopback-connector/lib/sql.js:413:7
```

Please find my [package.json](https://gist.github.com/sandipp/66a61e245681317b1d6b) 
I'm working on newly installed `loopback` app.
My connection with `redshift` was successful.

Comment: Apparently, this issue is related to `undefined` datatype for one of the column in your table. That's why `toUpperCase()` is not working on it.

If you can debug this file: `node_modules/loopback-connector-postgresql/lib/discovery.js` in line number 180 and `console.log(r);` to view datatypes for a given column.

Comment: @VishalKumar yeah, did the same thing and found out that, case for the variable's properties are mismatched; I've sent pull request for correct this issue.